# Unknown gaps in object in render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine

This is what it should look like. (EEVEE)
[image]

What it looks like. (CYCLES)
[image]

There's no modifiers in the object.

Comment: hello maybe you have a Displacement node in its material? Or please share your file

Comment: Thanks. It has a weird displacement i missed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *Displacement* node in its material.